# Resource Importer FTL Language Not Set

Tags: liferay

When I import my Liferay Freemarker templates using the Liferay resource importer their language value set to Velocity. This causes subsequent problems when Liferay tries to run them with Velocity. After import I have to manually change their language setting to Freemarker for my pages to run correctly.

Is there a way to import them so that the language is set to Freemarker?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably hit Liferay [issue](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-54576). Good news is that, it is already been resolved. You can check the committed files attached to LPS on left hand side.

HTH